# Visual Studio Code does not see changes in F# Solution

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

Currently I am trying to use Visual Studio Code with Ionide to build a F# Solution. To describe my problem, i first describe what i have done, and what works.

I created a solution with two Projects. One Project is a `Queue` that contains a F# library. Another project is `Queue.Test` that is a console application that uses the `Queue` library, and should contain the Tests for the `Queue` library.

I'm using .Net6 and created the solution and Project with the `dotnet` cli tool.

In general, i can build the project with `dotnet` and i also can use everything in Visual Studio Code. I load the Folder that contains both projects, and Visual Studio Code loads the library.

I am able to edit the Library and my Console application. In my Console application i also can access the `Queue` and so on. Autocompletion works, and so on.

But, there is one problem. When i add a new function to my library, let's say `Queue.help` then in my Console application, i cannot see that function. It doesn't show in autocomplete, and when I write code that uses that function i get a compiler error telling me that function doesn't exists.

I can Build/Rebuild from VS Code or from CLI but the problem goes not away.

The only way Ionide starts to see the new function is by building the library AND restarting VS Code. As long i don't restart, it seems to not update the generated dll (i guess).

This is sure annoying, as i don't want to reload/restart VSCode everytime I add a new function to my library.

So my question: How i can I fix this?

What i want is to be able to change my library, and at the same time write tests in the other project and get full Code autocompletion.

Does somebody else have the same problem, or should I change my workflow?

What can i do, to debug this problem on my own?

Some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed by the recent version of Ionide 5.10.1